# Show each first element in a list of parent elements (jQuery+CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm trying to show the first div for each section I have using jQuery. There's multiple parent elements `.each-business-content-extra` which has a few child elements `.each`. Each `.each` is set to display none via the CMS, but I want the first `.each` in each `.each-business-content-extra` that exists to be set to display:block.

I tried this —

```
$('.each-business-content-extra .each:first').each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a combination of everyones...

```
$('.each-business-content-extra').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.each:first').show();
});
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .eq() to target the first element of each .each class. http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Try this:

```
$('.each-business-content-extra .each:eq(0)').each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
$('.each-business-content-extra .each:eq(0)').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: Do you have the site I can see somewhere?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more code to try. I think this might solve it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  $('.each-business-content-extra').children(":first").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it your way, but the correct selector is `:first-of-type`:

```
$('.each-business-content-extra .each:first-of-type').each(function() {
  $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this simple one,

```
$('.each-business-content-extra .each:first-child').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.each-business-content-extra').find('.each:first').show()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qBdGU/)